# Pinch/Zoom & Scroll/Zoom to point in kinetic.js

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I am trying to implement zooming on my kineticjs project. I have found both of these sources that seem to work fine when they are implemented independently:

[Scroll wheel zoom to point on desktop](http://jsfiddle.net/FnwS5/78/)

[Pinch/zoom to point on mobile](https://github.com/eduplus/pinchlayer)

The problem is I need pinch/zoom when on mobile devices and scroll zoom when on desktop devices.

Does anyone have any example implementation of both methods on a kinetic.js project?
Thank you in advance.

**Scroll wheel zoom to point on desktop**

```
var ui = {
    stage: null,
    scale: 1,
    zoomFactor: 1.1,
    origin: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    },
    zoom: function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var evt = event.originalEvent,
            mx = evt.clientX /* - canvas.offsetLeft */ ,
            my = evt.clientY /* - canvas.offsetTop */ ,
            wheel = evt.wheelDelta / 120; //n or -n
        var zoom = (ui.zoomFactor - (evt.wheelDelta < 0 ? 0.2 : 0));
        var newscale = ui.scale * zoom;
        ui.origin.x = mx / ui.scale + ui.origin.x - mx / newscale;
        ui.origin.y = my / ui.scale + ui.origin.y - my / newscale;

        ui.stage.setOffset(ui.origin.x, ui.origin.y);
        ui.stage.setScale(newscale);
        ui.stage.draw();

        ui.scale *= zoom;
    }
};
```

**Pinch/zoom to point on mobile**

```
var layer = new Kinetic.Plugins.PinchLayer({
    container: stage,
    width: image.getWidth(),
    height: image.getHeight()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using [jquery.mousewheel](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel) for scrool:

```
$("#container").mousewheel(function(e, delta){
   // your zoom function
   camera.zoom(delta);
});
```

And [HammerJS](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/) for pinch zoom:

```
var transformer = Hammer(document.getElementById("container"));
var startScale;
transformer.on("transformstart", function (e) {
    startScale = camera.getScale();  // 
});
transformer.on("transform", function (e) {
    // setting new scale
    // or you can find delta here by youself
    camera.setScale(startScale * e.gesture.scale);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Why don't you use camera.draw() after the scaling?